# Fast package rebuilding inside cypress

Tags: build, cypress

I started fixing some issue in Cypress sourcecode (https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress). But to check my changes I had to do:
`yarn postinstall` which takes like 50 seconds.

Is there are faster way to rebuild cypress with only one package changed???
I know I could rebuild package inside 'packages\driver' but how to make that changes into whole project fast.

Comment: Cant you just do `yarn watch`. May be slow first time but then subsequent changes (you leave this watch process running) should be fast.

Comment: (Whilst that runs in one terminal, you have another that does `yarn cypress:open` or whatever once watch is ready.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below package\driver is package that I work on:

1. in main folder `yarn install` and wait until it finish
2. Change typescript version to one from main package (to get rid of problems in VSCode)
3. `cd packages\driver && yarn workspace @packages/runner watch`
4. Ctrl+Shift+` to open new terminal (or switch to second)
5. `yarn workspace @packages/driver cypress:open`
6. Now cypress Opens but to see changes we need to close cypress test window (Main window could stay open)